# Автоматический переход на другую страницу в angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

Как в angular осуществить автоматический переход на другую страницу?

Вот что я написал, но оно не работает))

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';

var status = true;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){}
  }

  if(true){
    this.router.navigate(['/start-loginregistry']);
  }
```

**То есть если какая-то переменная равна TRUE то переход на страницу Home. Если False то на страницу ABOUT**

Comment: что значит какая-то переменная? :) лучше приводи весь код, а не какой-то абстрактный)

Comment: Это и есть код, переменная - status = true

Answer (score 1):

В целом что-то странное у вас написанно, я бы посоветовал  сначала изучить основы, а потом лезть в фремворки, в классе нельзя вот так просто писать код вне методов или конструктора. Пример того что хотите снизу, с помощью хука ngOnInit жизненого цикла, вызывается сразу после конструктора и ngOnChanges.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public variable: boolean = true;

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.variable){
      this.router.navigate(['/start-loginregistry']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.router.navigate(this.variable ? ['/start-loginregistry'] : ['/about']);
```